# Iterate and compare two python dictionaries in most pythonic way for fast execution

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, optimization, numba

```
def formoutput(teams_id, patent_team):
    """
    The function to compare team_id and patent_teams to form the default dictionary matching values
    :param teams_id: {('3879797-2', '3930281-2'): 1, ('3930282-1', '3930282-2'): 2, ('3930288-1', '3930288-2'): 3, ... }
    :param patent_team: {3930281: [[('3879797-2', '3930281-2')]], 3930282: [[('3930282-1', '3930282-2')]], 3930288: [[('3930288-1', '3930288-2')]], ... }
    :return: defaultdict(<function formoutput.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000022A45228240>, {3930281: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'3879797-2': [1], '3930281-2': [1]}), 3930282: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'3930282-1': [2], '3930282-2': [2]}), 3930288: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'3930288-1': [3], '3930288-2': [3]}), 3930292: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'3861607-1': [4], '3861607-2': [4]}), ..}

    """
    print("Forming Output")
    print("Teams id =", teams_id)
    print("Patent_team=", patent_team)
    output_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    try:
        for k,v in teams_id.items():
            for a,b in patent_team.items():
                for i in b:
                    if k in i:
                        for z in k:
                            output_dict[a][z].append(v)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return output_dict
```

I have a function to which I pass two arguments in the form of python dictionaries. The keys of the first dictionary occur as the values in the second one. I need to compare if for each key from the first dictionary there exists a value in the second dictionary then, use the key, value from the first dictionary and key from the second dictionary to append the value into a defaultdict. Please have a look at the code above, it will help in the better understanding of code.
The multiple nested loops are making the code very slow. I have over 50 million key-value pair in the first dictionary. And over 3 million keys in the second dictiinary with each key containing an average of 3 values.

The entire idea behind the code is to find all the possible pairs of inventors that have ever worked on a patent in some combination and those are required as output with {patent_id: inventor_team, team_id}. Currently, it is taking hours to execute the same code. I ran it for 100,000 key value pairs and it took approximately 2000 seconds which is a lot of time.

Kindly provide me with the best possible approach for the overall solution. Also, what is the best way to deal with such huge amount of data?

Comment: I can't help but notice your inner `defaultdict(list)` never seem to have more than one entry in each `list`. Are you sure you need a `list` at all there?

Comment: Also, why are the `patent_team` values a one element `list` containing a one-element `list` containing a single two-`tuple`? Can either the inner or outer `list` contain more than one element? Can the inner two-`tuple` have a different number of elements?

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I initially tried making the defaultdict(int) but for keys which do not already exists it does not have an append method, hence I needed to add the extra code of lines to check if the key already exists and if not then initialize it to a list, in order to save myself from all of these I converted it to a list by default.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes the lists can contain more than one element in the list, I just printed out the few initial values for the reference. It can be like this.
'''
3930857: [[('3930857-1', '3930857-2'), ('3930857-1', '3930857-3'), ('3930857-2', '3930857-3')], [('3930857-1', '3930857-2', '3930857-3')]],
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list wrapping is really superfluous, and you ignore cases where the corresponding key isn't in `team_ids`, you can dramatically reduce the number of loops and membership tests here:

```
def formoutput(teams_id, patent_team):
    """
    The function to compare team_id and patent_teams to form the default dictionary matching values
    :param teams_id: {('3879797-2', '3930281-2'): 1, ('3930282-1', '3930282-2'): 2, ('3930288-1', '3930288-2'): 3, ... }
    :param patent_team: {3930281: [[('3879797-2', '3930281-2')]], 3930282: [[('3930282-1', '3930282-2')]], 3930288: [[('3930288-1', '3930288-2')]], ... }
    :return: defaultdict(<function defaultdict.copy>, {3930281: defaultdict(list, {'3879797-2': [1], '3930281-2': [1]}), 3930282: defaultdict(list, {'3930282-1': [2], '3930282-2': [2]}), 3930288: defaultdict(list, {'3930288-1': [3], '3930288-2': [3]}), 3930292: defaultdict(list, {'3861607-1': [4], '3861607-2': [4]}), ..}
    ...:
    """
    print("Forming Output")
    print("Teams id =", teams_id)
    print("Patent_team=", patent_team)
    # I hate lambdas, and as it happens, we don't need'em;
    # defaultdict(list).copy is cleaner and faster
    output_dict = defaultdict(defaultdict(list).copy)
    try:
        # [[pvs]] unpacks the superfluous(?) lists wrapping the tuple we care about
        for pk, [[pvs]] in patent_team.items():
            # Get the value to set once up front
            try:
                v = teams_id[pvs]
            except KeyError:
                continue  # Don't have a value to set, so move to next
            # Perform the first layer of dict lookup once since the key is the same
            # each time to avoid cost of repeated lookup
            pkdict = output_dict[pk]
            for pv in pvs:
                pkdict[pv].append(v)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return output_dict
```

I inverted the loops, since `patent_teams` keys are the keys of the outer result `defaultdict`, it makes sense to loop over `patent_teams` first, avoiding repeated lookups into `output_dict` for each `patent_teams` key. It also means you can use the value from `patent_teams` to directly look up what you need from `teams_id`, rather than iterating through `teams_id` to search.

If the `list` wrapping is not superfluous, replace:

```
for pk, [[pvs]] in patent_team.items():
```

with:

```
for pk, pvs_lists in patent_team.items():
    for pvs in chain.from_iterable(pvs_lists):
```

making sure to include the import `from itertools import chain` at the top of your file.

Comment: thank you for the insightful answer, I tried running it, but gave me an exception, "too many values to unpack (expected 1)". I tried fixing it, can you help me with that.

Comment: @BalvaishwerSalaria: Yeah, the unpacking assumed superfluous lists. Since it seems like only one layer of the `list` is superfluous (and it's the inner layer, so you can't just unpack the outer layer), I've added an alternative.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly fine, thank you so much for your answers. It was a great insight which increased the execution speed manifolds. It was great to learn all the stuff. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to improve, see which one is convenient for you:

First I would reverse the order of your loop:

```
for a,b in patent_team.items():
    for i in b:
        for k in i:
            if k in teams_id:
                for z in k:
                    output_dict[a][z].append(teams_id[k])
```

because I would assume `patent_teams` is a smaller dict than `teams_id` and I can make use of the O(1) lookup on `teams_id`, instead of the O(n) iteration on each item.

Second approach is to convert your data before combining. You can try iron out the two dictionaries into a tabular form and put it in pandas DataFrame or even save them into a database (SQLite in this case would be handy). The benefit of doing so is that you will probably offload your table join/DataFrame merge operation out of your Python interpreter. Thus faster.

Comment: thank you so much for the solution, it was so simple yet so difficult. I tried the first one it worked perfectly fine. However, how do you suggest following the second approach, if you could elucidate it.

Comment: Depends on your problem. If I need to do it over and over again, or some more complicated operations will be done, a SQLite database or pandas DataFrame will be handy. Especially I can save them into a file and move around. Also it is much easier to peek at the data than a plain dict.